# c# integration of 2 different projects

Tags: c#, dll, integration-testing, project

There is a project that implements a dll. There is another project that uses that dll, let's call it "calling" code. For both there is available the source code.
Is it possible to easily integrate into the calling code the source of the dll in order to change/debug together both and then to separate again to build exe and dll so that one can run the exe which will call the dll?
Now I am doing in such uncomfortable way :  I add the source of the dll to the project of the calling code, modify, build everything and test/debug.
When everything is ok I remove dll source from calling project, cut and paste it into the dll project. and build the dll. Finally I add the reference to the dll into the calling project, then build. I guess there is a better way.

Comment: Create an empty solution.  Add both projects to the solution.  If you create a _Project Reference_ to the called DLL from the Calling assembly, everything should just work (after, perhaps, a bit of tweaking)

Comment: When you say add both projects to the solution you mean to add the source code. I do not see the possibility a project to a solution. In reality when you create something new, you create a new project with the relevant solution associated.

Comment: Sorry for the errors, I meant to say that there is no possibility to add a "project" to a solution

Comment: Ok I never saw that under "File" menu there is the "add" where you can add a project. So I added the 2 projects to a new solution. Added also the reference to the dll to the calling assembly. Now I have to discover what happen when I build

Comment: When I build both dll and calling assembly are generated but not within their relevant release folder. Debug folders are updated after the building process with .dll and .exe

Comment: So it seems that, while developing, you have to reference the dll within the debug folder of the dll solution.

Comment: Create a blank solution in VS. Right-click the solution (in solution explorer), choose Add, Existing Project. Do that twice. Now, if proj A requires stuff from proj B, right click proj A in the solution explorer, choose Add, Reference. In the "References Manager", choose the Projects tab (Solution). Proj B should be shown. Select it, OK. Don't use the Browse tab, use the Projects tab (from memory, on my phone)